# Error on accessing model details in admin after upgrade to django 1.7

Tags: django, django-1.7

After upgrading to django 1.7, I get the following traceback, upon going to edit a model in the admin pages (IE clicking the entry of an individual model to access its details)

The app and admin appeared to be working after migration until I went to do this.   Obviously (?) I don't have tests for the admin side of things, so I only discovered this when I tried it.

Any idea what need to do to correct it?    Do I have some leftover old template from 1.6 that isn't supported, or have I failed to update something to work properly with a new one?

```
Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/cmh_server/module/7/
In template /Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html, 
error at line 45
'AdminErrorList' object has no attribute 'data'
35      {% if has_absolute_url %}<li><a href="{{ absolute_url }}" class="viewsitelink">{% trans "View on site" %}</a></li>{% endif%}
36      {% endblock %}
37    </ul>
38  {% endif %}{% endif %}
39  {% endblock %}
40  <form {% if has_file_field %}enctype="multipart/form-data" {% endif %}action="{{ form_url }}" method="post" id="{{ opts.model_name }}_form" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}{% block form_top %}{% endblock %}
41  <div>
42  {% if is_popup %}<input type="hidden" name="{{ is_popup_var }}" value="1" />{% endif %}
43  {% if to_field %}<input type="hidden" name="{{ to_field_var }}" value="{{ to_field }}" />{% endif %}
44  {% if save_on_top %}{% block submit_buttons_top %}{% submit_row %}{% endblock %}{% endif %}
45  {% if errors %}
46      <p class="errornote">
47      {% if errors|length == 1 %}{% trans "Please correct the error below." %}{% else %}{% trans "Please correct the errors below." %}{% endif %}
48      </p>
49      {{ adminform.form.non_field_errors }}
50  {% endif %}
51
```

---

Full traceback (wish I could post this "collapsed"!)

```
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  137.                 response = response.render()
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  103.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  80.         content = template.render(context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  148.             return self._render(context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  126.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  126.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "/Users/mgregory/Documents/virtualenvs/cm_central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  311.             if match:
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserList.py" in __len__
  30.     def __len__(self): return len(self.data)
Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/cmh_server/module/7/
Exception Value: 'AdminErrorList' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: Have you done : `python manage.py makemigrations yourappname` and `python manage.py migrate`   ?  you must do it after upgrading from 1.6 to 1.7 , makemigrations without appname won't fix it.

Comment: @CherifKAOUA Yes - I have done those.  I checked just now by running it again, and makemigrations said "no changes detected".   Last time it "did stuff" :)   I edited my question to be a bit more clear on _when_ the error is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was due to an out-of-date version of django-nested-inlines.

The clue for debugging came from asking "what is this AdminErrorList?", which lead to "what is in admin.py?", which lead to "whoa, what is this nested-lines thing, is it 1.7 compliant".

There was a recent commit on django-nested-inlines that referred to updates relating to AdminErrorList, and this change fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful questions that led to me being able to debug this!

Comment: Can you point to the commit that fixes this error? I'm also having this same weird error with an up-to-date django-nested-inlines installation.

Comment: I didn't bisect to prove it, but I think it's this one: https://github.com/silverfix/django-nested-inlines/commit/aeb7a1f84cd41acb8efa66483908f79a2fcd511a.   However, I just grabbed head from that repo and it worked for me.   FYI I made a fork to get rid of a deprecation warning: https://github.com/GreenAsJade/django-nested-inlines

Answer (score 1):

You probably got a secondary traceback. Try to get a primary one directly on the command line, not in the web browser. Try to reproduce the bug with:

```
python manage.py runserver --traceback --nothreading --noreload
```

Only the first option is very important. Other options only simplify the debugging.

Your error is in the class `ErrorList`. The class UserList is used only with Django 1.7, not with any older Django because it did not exist in any previous Django.

Comment: Hah!  You gave me a good and obvious reminder :)   In fact, the traceback I'm showing is in the console/log, where errors are directed.   But I didn't have DEBUG=True (doh!).   I will add the "primary" message that comes in the web page with DEBUG=True, in the question.

Comment: By a "secondary traceback" I mean that any problem is also in exception handling, reporting etc. Usually both need to be fixed. Maybe the first problem was only a missing user input for a required value in the form. The whole traceback consists only from nested rendering of template tags. It is not as much useful as knowledge of other information like the request URL, get/put, expected template for it, type of self object name at every level of the traceback.